# Access VBA calling function does nothing when run

Tags: vba, function, ms-access

I have a macro that I'm trying to build in Access which will change the source table on a set of queries. Here is what I've built (based off already written code that I found on a forum):

```
Function ReplaceSources()

Call SourceQueries

End Function

Sub SourceQueries()

Call UpdateSource("YYYY_Count_of_items_by_floor", Building_Audit_2021, Building_Audit_YYYY)

End Sub

Sub UpdateSource(QueryName, CurrentSourceTable, NewSourceTable)

Dim strQryName, strCTbl, strNTbl, strCsql, strNsql As String
Dim defqry As DAO.QueryDef

strQryName = QueryName
strCTbl = CurrentSourceTable
strNTbl = NewSourceTable

Set defqry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(strQryName)

strCsql = defqry.SQL
strNsql = Replace(strCsql, strCTbl, strNTbl)
defqry.SQL = strNsql
defqry.Close

End Sub
```

When I use the RunCode option in the macro builder using function name ReplaceSources(), nothing happens. I get no errors, I can step through the code with no issues, and adding Debug.Print lines throughout the function and subs does nothing. What is preventing this function from doing anything?

ETA:
Maybe it will help if I add the other two parts of code that I'm piecing together with this one. Before the above code, I run:

```
Function Copy_audit_table()
On Error GoTo Copy_audit_table_Err

    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = CurrentProject.FullName
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", strPath, acTable, "Building_Audit_2021", "Building_Audit_YYYY", True
    DoCmd.CopyObject "", "YYYY_Count_of_items_by_floor", acQuery, "2021_Count_of_items_by_floor"
    
Copy_audit_table_Exit:
    Exit Function

Copy_audit_table_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Copy_audit_table_Exit

End Function
```

Then after the code in question, I run:

```
Function Copy_audit_table_rename()
On Error GoTo Copy_audit_table_rename_Err

    Dim AuditYear As Variant
    AuditYear = InputBox("Enter audit year (YYYY)")
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = CurrentProject.FullName
    DoCmd.Rename "Building_Audit_" & AuditYear, acTable, "Building_Audit_YYYY"
    DoCmd.Rename AuditYear & "_Count_of_items_by_floor", acQuery, "YYYY_Count_of_items_by_floor"
    
Copy_audit_table_rename_Exit:
    Exit Function

Copy_audit_table_rename_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Copy_audit_table_rename_Exit

End Function
```

I'm not too familiar with VBA, so most of this is code that I found elsewhere that I was able to piece together. I know that I can use the macro builder to run each Function, but I really don't know any other ways. If there are any recommended tutorials that will help me code what I want to do, I'd like to read them.

Comment: Please, before you do anything else, put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module. 
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor. 
This is really a must have for VBA development.

Comment: Why use macro? Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: Once I added Option Explicit, I got a message of "Variable not defined" on the two table names. I enclosed these in quotes which prevented the error from popping up again, but it still does nothing when run.

Answer (score 0):

You must execute the query for something to happen.

And skip the macro and the function. All you need is to call:

```vb
Sub UpdateSource(QueryName As String, CurrentSourceTable As String, NewSourceTable As String)

    Dim strCsql As String
    Dim defqry  As DAO.QueryDef

    Set defqry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName)

    strCsql = defqry.SQL
    strNsql = Replace(strCsql, CurrentSourceTable, NewSourceTable)
    
    defqry.SQL = strNsql
    defqry.Execute
    defqry.SQL = strCsql
    defqry.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the solution I was looking for. The point of what I'm doing is that this is part of a 3 step macro that copies a table and its associated queries, replaces the source table on all the queries with the new one, then renames all pieces to replace "YYYY" using a message box that asks for a current year.

I'm trying to build this into a macro so that one button click will get the table and queries set up each year. And no, I don't want to combine all years into one table, I want them to be kept separate.

Comment: Well, we only have the info and question you post. For a wider scenario, adjust/expand the code as needed. But do get rid of the macro stuff, it is a dead end.